# Spring Boot 404 and CORS on tomcat 9 server with Angular application

Tags: angular, spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat9

I run a WAMP Server and a tomcat server containing angular application and Springboot app. I have 404 while I think i meet all requirements not to have such issue. At the same time my front app is returning cors errors.

1. Add the dependencies in my pom xml to generate war
2. Update my main class to allow war generation
3. Managing the access to public routes
4. Handling cors management
5. Managing cors in WebSecurity

I have this pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>fr.dsidiff.proxy.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-proxy</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-proxy</name>
    <description>springboot-proxy</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <tomcat.version>9.0.54</tomcat.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-hateoas -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I also defined some params in my application.properties (even context path) :

```
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my-db
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
server.port=8080
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
server.servlet.context-path=/springboot-proxy
```

Nothing really special. As I want to build jar, I didn't forget to modify the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootProxyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    // allow to generate a war file
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(SpringbootProxyApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootProxyApplication.class, args);
    }
```

That's good. As it's a rest API i also added a get call for test purpose :

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ws")
public class DummyController {
    @GetMapping
    public String dummy() throws IOException {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

I implemented Spring Security and i want those routes to be public so i implemented the configure method

```
@Override
protected  void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // define public & private entry points
    http
            .cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/ws").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/ws/**").permitAll()
```

While running my mvn clean package i do build my API. I do upload my jar using the tomcat manager. And it's working fine. I also added Cors management of course ...

I implemented this in my web security:

```
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

    corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));

    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
    return source;
}
```

And if it was not enough:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```

In my front I have this response:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/springboot-proxy/ws/getCategories' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

And when i try to call the get method from my dummyController, I have a nice 404 error. I don't really understand what's going wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I ran `catalina.bat run` before uploading the war file through the manager and it worked.